# Alter Table Add Column and update the new Column in the same conditional IF statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I'm trying to add column and update it in the same if statement:

```
BEGIN TRAN

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns 
              WHERE Name = N'Code' 
              AND Object_ID = Object_ID(N'TestTable'))
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE TestTable 
    ADD Code NVARCHAR(10)

    UPDATE TestTable 
    SET Code = Name 
    WHERE 1=1
END

COMMIT
```

It throws an error:

> Invalid column name 'Code'

Is there any ways how to do these operations in one transaction?

Comment: No, it's not a really idea to mix DDL (`ATLER TABLE`) and DML statements. You need to **first** execute (and commit) the `ALTER TABLE` , and only once that's done can you refer to the newly added column in a DML statement

Answer (score 1):

You can use the EXEC statement to accomplish this.

```
BEGIN TRAN

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 from sys.columns where Name = N'Code' and Object_ID = Object_ID(N'TestTable'))
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE TestTable ADD Code NVARCHAR(10)

    Exec ('UPDATE TestTable SET Code = Name WHERE 1=1')
END

COMMIT
```

This is the test code I used.

```
Create Table TestTable(Id Int, Name VarChar(20))

Insert Into TestTable Values(1,'George')

BEGIN TRAN

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 from sys.columns where Name = N'Code' and Object_ID = Object_ID(N'TestTable'))
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE TestTable ADD Code NVARCHAR(10)

    Exec ('UPDATE TestTable SET Code = Name WHERE 1=1')
END

COMMIT

Select * From TestTable

Drop Table TestTable
```

Comment: I just tested this and it works.  I will update my answer with the complete test I used.

Answer (score 1):

You are running into the issue whereby the entire statement is parsed, and the DML fails  because the `Code` column doesn't exist yet. You now have the conflict:

- `ALTER TABLE` requires a `GO` (batch execution)
- Your multi line batch logic requires a BEGIN / END wrapper

You'll need to find another way to retain the state of 'Add Code' logic across multiple statement batches, e.g. use a `#temp` table:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpFlag(AddCode BIT);

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 from sys.columns where Name = N'Code' and Object_ID = Object_ID(N'TestTable'))
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #tmpFlag VALUES(1);
    ALTER TABLE TestTable ADD Code NVARCHAR(10);
END;
GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #tmpFlag)
BEGIN
   UPDATE TestTable SET Code = Name;
END;

DROP TABLE #tmpFlag;
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7e595/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, see the live example in SQL Server 2008
[image]

```
BEGIN TRAN

    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 from sys.columns where Name = N'Code' and Object_ID = Object_ID(N'TestTable'))
    BEGIN
        ALTER TABLE TestTable ADD Code NVARCHAR(10)
        Go
        SET XACT_ABORT ON
        Go
        UPDATE TestTable SET Code = Name WHERE 1=1
    END

    COMMIT
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need `begin tran` since both `ALTER` & `UPDATE` are `TRANSACTION`.

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns 
              WHERE Name = N'Code' 
              AND Object_ID = Object_ID(N'TestTable'))
BEGIN
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE TestTable 
    ADD Code NVARCHAR(10)
END
GO
BEGIN
    UPDATE TestTable 
    SET Code = Name 
    WHERE 1=1
END
GO
END
```